# Tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, tar

I am trying to make a create a backup bash script from multiple source dir to a different destination dir.

So I used find to search for source dir folder name, save it into variable and use it for tar filenames.

I also pointed tar source dir to $file instead but when I execute the script, it returns an error (Tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory)

```
for file in `find $src_dir -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name $skip_containers -prune -o -printf '%f\n' | grep -v "\.$"`; do 
  echo "Compressing $file..."
  tar zcf "$backup_dir/$file.tar.gz" -T $file 
done
```

Variable used

1. `src_dir`=pointing to the origin of my backup data
2. `skip_containers`=some directories I am skipping
3. `backup_dir`=pointing to a external backup drive (same filesystem as my source)
4. `file`=for tar filename and also source dir loop

File structure

```
/path/to/data/
    ├── dir1
    ├── dir2
    ├── dir3
    ├── dir4
```

Desirable result is to create tar for each dir and backup into external dir

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Once you fix the issues that shellcheck will tell you about then ask a question here if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent *word splitting*:

```
find ...... -print0 |
    xargs -0 tar zcf "$backup_dir/$file.tar.gz"
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. but this kinda save a list of filenames with .txt extension and tar those files only. I am still not able to tar the directories

Comment: This is to adapt to your output. Do you think you can do it?

Comment: I don't think I could. tried a number of different ways but just can't manage to get it working :(